# How can I execute a python flask web app with xampp?

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a web app in python with flask and I don't know how to test my app in xampp apache server. When I go to the xampp dashboard and open the .py file, the browser only shows me the .py code and doesn't execute anything. The .py file hasn't get html code. I want to know how to execute the .py file to see the .html and its funcionality in the browser. This is the code of the .py file:

```
#C:\Python27\python.exe -u
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, escape, 
url_for, redirect
from hashlib import md5
import MySQLdb, sys, pdb
import cgi

app = Flask(__name__)

# if __name__ == '__main__':
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root",
                     passwd="root", db="prueba")
cur = db.cursor()
app.secret_key = 'mysecretkey'


class ServerError(Exception):
   pass

# METODO DE LA PAGINA HOME DE ADMIN


@app.route('/')
def home():

    #Si esta la sesion iniciada, cargamos la pagina home con la sesion iniciada

    if 'username' in session:
        username_session = escape(session['username']).capitalize()

        return render_template('home.html', 
session_user_name=username_session, adminIs = True)

    #Si no esta la sesion iniciada, cargamos la pagina home sin la sesion iniciada

    return render_template('home.html')

app.secret_key='A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This code only shows one function to show the home page .html but I want the browser, when I go to one of the pages, show the .html (with embebed php code) the data I bring from mysql server.

Comment: You may need mod_wsgi enabled and configured to execute a flask application within Apache. For testing purposes you can use Flask's internal server (`flask run`). You could also use gunicorn to serve your application locally.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Why is it tagged with PHP?

Comment: Cause in the hmtl pages has embebed php code to bring data from mysql. This is why I need an Apache Server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the apache server from xampp to execute python scripts. So edit the httpd.conf in your xampp/apache folder and add the following at the end of the file:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

Restart xampp and youre .py file should be executed.

Comment: Should be executed, but the .py file doesn't have html code. I've tried to execute a .py file with simply html code and it works, but with the code i've show doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try to run the code via flask run to see if it generally works?

Comment: I've already tried it but I got an error (Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP"
 environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the c
urrent directory.)

Comment: On command line use `set FLASK_APP=<name_of_your_app.py>`. FLASK_APP also can be a package like `myapplication/__init__.py` by creating `app` in that file. You can find everything you need at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

i know it was posted long time ago, recently i had the similar requirement
i will demonstrate how to deploy python flask app on **Apache2.4** with minimal dummy flask app ( same can be tested on your xampp server)

#### prerequisite

download Apache2.4 https://www.apachelounge.com/download/ unzip it and paste the Apache24 to C:/Apache24

add to path  **MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR="C:\Apache24"**

install apache server as a windows server
        > **C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe -k install**

download the mod_wsgi from the https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
    install the mod_wsgi wheel file
    > **python -m pip install <*.whl file>**

from command line run the following
    > **mod_wsgi-express module-config**

paste the above output to the httpd.conf file in the last line

paste the following after the previous step

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
    <VirtualHost *:5000>
        ServerName 127.0.0.1
        WSGIScriptAlias /myapp C:/Apache24/htdocs/flaskapp/my_app.wsgi
        <Directory C:/Apache24/htdocs/flaskapp>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +Includes +ExecCGI
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog "D:/var/logs/error.log"
        CustomLog "D:/var/logs/access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

my application resides in **C:\Apache24\htdocs\flaskapp** which has **my_app.py** and **my_app.wsgi**

Restart the Apache24 service from windows service management
    **windows + R** --> services.msc --> search for Apache24 --> restart

go to browser
    http://localhost:5000/myapp

**NOTE**: myapp is an alias name given in the VirtualHost tag

Answer (score 0):

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='mysql://medclub:sandip123@localhost:3306/dbsite'`

This works for me.

Comment: this is better off as a comment rather than an answer